# Can I add common argument to subparsers AFTER the subparser arguments?

Tags: python, parsing

I have 2 subparsers:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--say')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', help='what should I do')
a = subparsers.add_parser('eat')
a.add_argument('food')

b = subparsers.add_parser('drink')
b.add_argument('beverage')

print(parser.parse_args(['eat', 'apple']))
print(parser.parse_args(['drink', 'water']))
print(parser.parse_args(['--say', 'thanks', 'drink', 'water'])) # Works, but I don't like it
print(parser.parse_args(['drink', 'water', '--say', 'thanks'])) # I want this to work
```

```
Namespace(action='eat', food='apple', say=None)
Namespace(action='drink', beverage='water', say=None)
Namespace(action='drink', beverage='water', say='thanks')
usage: test.py [-h] [--say SAY] {eat,drink} ...
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --say thanks
```

Adding parents gets everything complicated...

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('--say')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', help='what should I do')
a = subparsers.add_parser('eat', parents=[parser])
a.add_argument('food')

b = subparsers.add_parser('drink', parents=[parser])
b.add_argument('beverage')

print(parser.parse_args(['eat', 'apple']))
```

```
usage: test.py eat [-h] [--say SAY] {eat,drink} ... food
test.py eat: error: invalid choice: 'apple' (choose from 'eat', 'drink')
```

Suddenly nothing works because I have to input "eat" **TWICE**??? (the 2nd time is for the action, but why do I need the 1st?)

All I want is to have a shared argument, that I can add at the end, or the start of my argument list (to my choosing), for multiple subparsers, i.e. I want all of the following to work:

1. test.py eat apple --say thanks
2. test.py --say grace drink coffee
3. test.py --say grace eat bread --clap hands (if I add another shared argument)

Answer (score 2):

Once `parse_args` has recognized the subcommand, all further arguments are passed to the subparser, not the main parser. Using `parents=` inherits *all* arguments, including the subcommands, not just the other options.

Instead, you want yet *another* parser that does nothing except provide `--say`; you can then use that as a parent for each of the main parser and its two subparsers.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

say_parser = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
say_parser.add_argument('--say')

parser = ArgumentParser(parents=[say_parser])

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', help='what should I do')
a = subparsers.add_parser('eat', parents=[say_parser])
a.add_argument('food')

b = subparsers.add_parser('drink', parents=[say_parser])
b.add_argument('beverage')

print(parser.parse_args(['eat', 'apple']))
print(parser.parse_args(['drink', 'water']))
print(parser.parse_args(['--say', 'thanks', 'drink', 'water']))
print(parser.parse_args(['drink', 'water', '--say', 'thanks']))
```

If you don't want the third one to work, you can omit the `say_parser` from the parent list of the main parser.

Comment: I am content with having the order matter, as long as the sub-command is first (i.e. `eat food --say thanks` is OK by me, where I have no problem with not accepting `--say thanks eat food` )

Comment: inheriting all subcommands - is that the reason for the 2 `eat`? I find it very silly...

Comment: A subcommand is just an ordinary positional argument that, when recognized, selects which subparser to defer to. Rather than something like `add_argument('subcmd', choices=['eat', 'drink'])`, the definition gets spread across multiple calls to `subparser.add_parser`.